How to attach file in requests post in Python?
I am trying to use the dribbble.com API to upload shots with Python. Here is their documentation: https://developer.dribbble.com/v2/shots/#create-a-shot, and the image attached is the relevant portion. The image parameter is meant to be a file type, but I'm unsure how to do that within python requests.
So far I have tried to do the following, with my code attached. I have tried the endpoints users/shots and just /shots:

include the file in params with open(myPath, "rb"), similar to how requests documentation recommends.
included the data as data and the type in headers.

1 is giving the clearest error, 414, but I'm not sure why still. 2 gives error 403, whether or not I include the user-agent. Current code has 1, with 2 commented out. With the endpoint user/shots I get error 414 in 1 and 404 in 2.
    #data = open(myPath, "rb")
    #headers = {"content-type" : "image/jpg", "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9"}
    params = {
        "image" : open(myPath, "rb"),
        "title" : myCaption
    }
    r = requests.post("https://api.dribbble.com/v2/shots?access_token="+DRIBBBLE_ACCESSTOKEN, params=params) #, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(r)


With requests, you use the files argument to upload files as part of a form:
    form_data = {
        "title": myCaption,
    }
    files = {
        "image": open(myPath, "rb"),
    }
    r = requests.post(
        "https://api.dribbble.com/v2/shots?access_token="+DRIBBBLE_ACCESSTOKEN,
        data=form_data,
        files=files,
    )

The params argument is for params that are part of the URL. This is true even for POST requests, params is appended to the URL. That is why you are getting 414 URI too long.

I'm getting error 422 now, some sort of semantic issue I think? I tried with and without these headers:
headers = { "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", "Referer" : "https://api.dribbble.com/", "content-type" : "image/jpeg"}

Got the response JSON, without headers:
{'message': 'Validation failed.', 'errors': [{'attribute': 'image', 'message': 'is an invalid file type'}]}
and with headers:
{'message': 'Validation failed.', 'errors': [{'attribute': 'title', 'message': "can't be blank"}, {'attribute': 'image', 'message': "can't be blank"}]}
I have no idea why it thinks these are blank

And if I include the "title" as a param, it only gives me image can't be blank error
